# Gamma CDF and inverse CDF not producing compliment values

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

Why isn't the inverse gamma function producing the original x value?

Code

```
x = 0.2
alpha = 2
u = sp.stats.gamma.cdf(x, alpha)
x1 = sp.stats.invgamma.cdf(x, alpha)
print "x: ", x
print "G: ", u
print "GInv:", x1
```

Output

```
x:  0.2
G:  0.0175230963064
GInv: 0.0404276819945
```

When I perform a similar operation in Excel I get the same value back.

```
=GAMMADIST(Q15,2,1,TRUE)
=GAMMA.INV(Q16,2,1)
```

Output

```
0.2
0.017523096
0.2
```

I know I'm just overlooking something, but I can't seem to figure out why the inverse isn't working for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `scipy.stats`, `gamma` is the [gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) and `invgamma` is the [inverse gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution).  These are two different probability distributions--see the wikipedia article for the relation of the inverse gamma to the gamma distribution.

If you want the inverse of `gamma.cdf`, use `gamma.ppf`.  (The acronym `ppf` stands for [*percent point function*](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda362.htm#PPF), which is another name for the [*quantile function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function).)

For example,

```
In [7]: p = gamma.cdf([1, 2, 3], 0.5)

In [8]: gamma.ppf(p, 0.5)
Out[8]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

Comment: Right there in the docs, too. "Percent point function (inverse of cdf — percentiles)." I knew I was overlooking something. I appreciate the help!